# Terms of Consent popup not showing at signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am following this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) in order to enhance an existent custom policy. However, can't get prompted for the `Terms of Conditions` checkbox at local signup even though  I've specified it as a required field on the output claims.

The technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-HasEmailFlagged">
    <DisplayName>Sign Up with Local Email</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
      <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
      <Item Key="language.button_continue">Sign Up</Item>
      <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCurrentDateTime" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" DefaultValue="AgreeToTermsOfUseConsentNo" />
    </InputClaims>
    <DisplayClaims>
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    </DisplayClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
      
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyGivenName" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>          
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WriteUserHasPassword" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/>
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was using `DisplayClaim` and `OutputClaim` the wrong way. The following fixed the issue.

```xml
<DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
  <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" 
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" Required="true" />
  Required="true" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsOfUseConsentChoice" />
  </OutputClaims>
```